# How to efficiently find all Hamiltonian paths in an undirected graph, withou just using DFS?

Tags: algorithm, performance, graph, depth-first-search, hamiltonian-path

I have problem where i need to display all nodes which are included in a path(from source to destination), but in such a way  that we visit every node in the path only once.
Solution with only DFS (and marking visited elements) is not fast enough.
Someone told me to use articulation points, but i do not see how to do that.
Can you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: DFS is a distributed filesystem from Microsoft. Note: for questions about depth-first search, please use the depth-first-search tag. **NOT to be confused** with [depth-first-search]

Comment: Your question title talks about listing all Hamiltonian paths, but your question body only talks about paths that don't repeat nodes. Can you clarify what you're asking?